# Why i cannot coonect to my twitter project?

Tags: python, api, twitter, bots, twitterapi-python

Since yesterday i'm trying to create a bot for twitter just for the pleasure. I look on googl eand youtube how to start, i make the basics like this :

```
API_KEY = "***************"
API_SECRET = "******************"

ACCESS_TOKEN = "*********************"
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = "***********************"

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(API_KEY, API_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

try :
    api.verify_credentials()
    print("ok")
except :
    print("not ok")
```

But when i try to run my code it doesn't work, it goes in the "except" and i don't know why.

[Here the result when i try to run my python code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQCXp.png)

All the tokens are correct i have the permission enable in my project page on twitter and i already try to regenerate the tokens

Please help me, i didn't even start the project and i'm already blocked, thank you !

(I replace my token to "*")

Comment: This question isn't really concerning the code itself as it is correct. This is almost certainly an issue with the API code which you've received and can't really be answered here unless you revise how you've written this question.

Comment: one tip is to take `api.verify_credentials()` out of the try/except block so that it can report the actual error instead of masking it with "not okay"

Comment: yes, don't mask your errors!